# Remove incomplete months from a data frame even when part of the month contains data

Tags: r, data-management

I would like to remove incomplete months from my data frame even if some of the month has data.

Example data frame:

```
date <- seq.Date(as.Date("2016-01-15"),as.Date("2016-09-19"),by="day")
data <- seq(1:249)

df <- data.frame(date,data)
```

What I would like:

```
date2 <- seq.Date(as.Date("2016-02-01"),as.Date("2016-08-31"),by="day")
data2 <- seq(from = 18, to = 230)

df2 <- data.frame(date2,data2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I interpreted your question correctly, you want to be able to select the months that have a **complete number of days**, removing those that don't.

The following uses `dplyr v0.7.0`:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>%
  mutate(mo = months(date)) # add month (mo)

complete_mo <- df %>%
  count(mo) %>% #count number of days in month (n)
  filter(n >= 28) %>% #rule of thumb definition of a `complete month`
  pull(mo)

df_complete_mo <- df %>%
  filter(mo %in% complete_mo) %>% # here is where you select the complete months
  select(-mo) #remove mo, to keep your original df
```

Then `df_complete_mo` yields your dataset with just **complete months**.

Answer (score 1):

You could join a complete set of dates for each month to your data frame and then filter out months with any missing values.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df.filtered = data.frame(date=seq(min(df$date)-31,max(df$date)+31,by="day")) %>%
  left_join(df) %>%
  group_by(month=month(date)) %>%   # Add a month column and group by it
  filter(!any(is.na(data))) %>%     # Remove months with any missing data
  ungroup %>%                       
  select(-month)                    # Remove the month column

# A tibble: 213 x 2
         date  data
       <date> <int>
 1 2016-02-01    18
 2 2016-02-02    19
 3 2016-02-03    20
 4 2016-02-04    21
 5 2016-02-05    22
 6 2016-02-06    23
 7 2016-02-07    24
 8 2016-02-08    25
 9 2016-02-09    26
10 2016-02-10    27
# ... with 203 more rows
```

Comment: I am getting the following error when I apply your code to my "real" dataset: `Error in min(df$date) - 31 : non-numeric argument to binary operator`. Does this relate to how date is formatted?

Comment: If your dates are in character format rather than in Date format (Date format is really a numeric format with a Date class attached) then you'll get an error.

Answer (score 0):

In base R, you could do the following.

```
# get start and end dates of months that are are beyond the sample
dateRange <- as.Date(format(range(df$date) + c(-32, 32), c("%Y-%m-2", "%Y-%m-1"))) - 1
```

the second argument of format is a vector that separately formats the min and the max dates. We subtract 1 from these dates to get the first day of a month and the last day of a month. This returns

```
dateRange
[1] "2015-12-01" "2016-09-30"
```

Now, use `which.max` to select the first date that matches and `which` with `tail` to select the last day that matches monthly sequences in order to figure out the starting and stopping rows of your data.frame.

```
startRow <- which.max(df$date %in% seq(dateRange[1], dateRange[2], by="month"))
stopRow <- tail(which(df$date %in% (seq(dateRange[1], dateRange[2], by="month")-1)), 1)
```

Now, subset your data.frame

```
dfNew <- df[startRow:stopRow,]

range(dfNew$date)
[1] "2016-02-01" "2016-08-31"
nrow(dfNew)
[1] 213
```